# Generate raw json array into view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to generate a piece of javascript as part of the view rendering. I have a model that expose an array of simple types and I would like to generate a javascript/json equivalent array into the view so that I can act on it using jQuery. So given the following model:

```
public class Info {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int ID {get; set;}
}

public class InfoModel{
   public Info[] InfoList {get;set;}
}
```

...I would like to generate a javascript array looking like this:

```
var infoList = [
      {
         Name = "...",
         ID = 1
      } ,
      {
         Name = "...",
         ID = 2
      },
      ....
      {
         Name = "...",
         ID = N
      }];
```

Is there a nice and concise way to do this in the view, I seem to have trouble with encoding of quotes if I try to have the model generate a json representation, so currently I can only have it generated using some spaghetti/classic asp code that I would rather have replaced by a nice one-liner.

EDIT: Note that I'm not looking for away to have a controller return a JsonResult, I want a way for my view to contain a javascript array that is generated from my model in a single line of code (if possible)

EDIT:
I got part of the way, but seems to be struggling with encoding. This code in the view:

```
<script>
var list = <%: HtmlExtension.ToJson(Model.InfoList) %>;
</script>
```

(where ToJson encapsulates conversion to string using JavaScriptSerializer) outputs some encoding faults:

```
var info = [{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Low End&quot;,&quot;ID&quot;:1}];
```

..which is not what I was looking for. I could do this:

```
var info = <% Response.Write(HtmlExtension.ToJson(Model.InfoList)); %>;
```

which works, but doesn't look as shiny. Should I explicitly ignore encoding as shown (The output is sane, not user generated, so it may not be a problem) or am I missing something else that makes it less classic asp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have an encoding problem. I believe you have two choices here:

1. When you create your extension, be sure that it returns `MvcHtmlString` instead of a normal `string`, or...
2. Instead of using the `<%: ... %>` style to write out your code, use `<%= ... %>` to not do encoding.

Comment: I was able to use this line of code in my razor HTML file:
MvcHtmlString.Create(Json.Encode(Model))

Comment: Exactly. In the end it is `MvcHtmlString` is the key to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a nice way:

```
InfoModel viewModel; // get this from wherever
return Json(viewModel);
```

MVC will translate the collection to the relevant JSON.

This will return a **JsonResult** (ie raw JSON).

Is that what you're after?

If you wanted to do something like this in your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
   var json = <%: Model.JsonStuff %>
   // more js
</script>
```

Then above example won't work.

You'll have to serialize it manually when you construct your ViewModel.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of how you could serialize your data.

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var listOfInfos; // this will be a collection (e.g List) of Infos.
var viewModel = new InfoModel
                {
                   InfoList = js.Serialize(listOfInfos);
                };
return View(viewModel);
```

As long as **listOfInfo's** implements IEnumerable, it will serialize to a JSON array.

You might have to play around with your viewmodel a bit, but that should put you on the right track.

Comment: I'm looking for the second option, rendering json into the view, not having a controller action return json. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, tried your approach and it didn't quite work. Please see my updated question (ToJson encapsulates the js.Serialize call to keep that out of the viewmodel)

Comment: Looks like you got it sorted, im glad.